# How can I mark the intersection of lines and curves with letters and coordinate values?

Tags: plotting

Consider:

```
ClearAll["`*"]
eqs = {x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1, x == 2 y + 1};
line = eqs[[2]]
ell = eqs[[1]]
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}];
normalized = First[ell] - Last[ell];
ax = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]]
bx = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]
(*ass=ResourceFunction["EllipseProperties"][ell,{x,y}];
params={a->ass["SemimajorAxisLength"],b->ass["SemiminorAxisLength"]}*)\
params = {a -> Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]],
  b -> Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]}
glin = line[[2]] /. params
gell = b {-1, 1} Sqrt[1 - x^2/a^2] /. params;
gpts = pts /. params;
(*Hold@ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eqs},{x,-a-1,a+1},{y,-b-0.5,b+0.5},\
PlotLegends->Placed[eqs,{0.8,0.15}],AspectRatio->Automatic,Frame->\
False,Axes->True,AxesStyle->Arrowheads[{0.0,0.04}],AxesLabel->{x,y}]/. \
params//ReleaseHold*)
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{eqs}, {x, -ax - 1, ax + 1}, {y, -bx - 0.5, bx + 0.5},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[gpts]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[eqs, {0.8, 0.15}], AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

How can I mark letters (A and B) on the intersection points of lines and curves in the diagram and the coordinate values of the intersection points in the diagram?

Update 1:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqs = {x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1, y == 2 x + 1};
line = eqs[[2]]
ell = eqs[[1]]
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}];
normalized = First[ell] - Last[ell];
ax = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]]
bx = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]
p = Plot[y /. Solve[line, y], {x, -ax - 0.5, ax + 0.5}];
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}]
(*Graphics[{{First@p},{Red,Circle[{0,0},{ax,bx}],Point[{0,0}]},{Blue,\
PointSize[.03],Point[pts]}},Axes->True,AxesLabel->{x,y},AxesStyle->\
Arrowheads[{0.0,0.04}],AspectRatio->1]*)
(*ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eqs},{x,-ax-1,ax+1},{y,-bx-0.5,bx+0.5},Epilog->\
{Red,PointSize[0.02],Point[pts]},PlotLegends->Placed[eqs,{0.8,0.15}],\
AspectRatio->Automatic,Frame->False,Axes->True,AxesStyle->Arrowheads[{\
0.0,0.04}],AxesLabel->{x,y}]*)
plx = Apply[Subtract, eqs, {1}];
pls = Numerator[Together[Apply[Subtract, eqs, {1}]]];
xpl = Collect[Resultant[pls[[1]], pls[[2]], y], x];
Collect[Coefficient[xpl, x^2] x^2 +
   Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[xpl, x], x] x +
   Select[xpl, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &] == 0
Collect[xpl, x, Simplify];
pl = {% == 0}
discx = Factor[Discriminant[xpl, x]]   (*discriminant*)
frist = Solve[eqs, {x, y}] // FullSimplify;
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = {x, y} /. frist;
second = {x1 + x2, x1 x2, y1 + y2, y1 y2,
   y1 y2/(x1 x2), (x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2} // FullSimplify
thrid = {x1 x2 + y1 y2, x1 y2 + x2 y1} // FullSimplify
slope = CoefficientList[line[[2]], x][[2]];    (*k*)
intercept = CoefficientList[line[[2]], x][[1]];  (*m*)
Chordlength =
 FullSimplify[
  Sqrt[1 + slope^2] Sqrt[(x1 + x2)^2 - 4 x1 x2]]    (*AbsAB*)
area = 1/2 Chordlength Sqrt[intercept^2]/Sqrt[slope^2 + 1] //
  FullSimplify
Legended[
 Show[ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[eqs], {x, -ax - 0.5, ax + 0.75}, {y, -bx - 0.5,
    bx + 0.75},
   PlotLegends ->
    Placed[LineLegend[eqs, LegendLayout -> "Column"], Below],
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, Axes -> True,
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}],
  ListPlot[{{Tooltip[Callout[pts[[1]], "A", Before]]}, {Tooltip[
      Callout[pts[[2]], "B", Above]]}},
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]}, {Purple,
      AbsolutePointSize[4]}}]],
 Placed[PointLegend[{Red, Purple},
   Row /@ Thread[{{"A = ", "B = "}, pts}]], Below]]
```

Update 2:

```
ClearAll["`*"]
eqs = {x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1, x == 2 y + 1};
line = eqs[[2]]
ell = eqs[[1]]
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}];
normalized = First[ell] - Last[ell];
ax = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]]
bx = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]
p = Plot[y /. Solve[line, y], {x, -ax - 0.5, ax + 0.5}];
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}]
(*Graphics[{{First@p},{Red,Circle[{0,0},{ax,bx}],Point[{0,0}]},{Blue,\
PointSize[.03],Point[pts]}},Axes->True,AxesLabel->{x,y},AxesStyle->\
Arrowheads[{0.0,0.04}],AspectRatio->Automatic]*)
(*ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eqs},{x,-ax-1,ax+1},{y,-bx-0.5,bx+0.5},Epilog->\
{Red,PointSize[0.02],Point[pts]},PlotLegends->Placed[eqs,{0.8,0.15}],\
AspectRatio->Automatic,Frame->False,Axes->True,AxesStyle->Arrowheads[{\
0.0,0.04}],AxesLabel->{x,y}]*)
polyex = Apply[Subtract, eqs, {1}];
polys = Numerator[Together[Apply[Subtract, eqs, {1}]]];
xpoly = Collect[Resultant[polys[[1]], polys[[2]], x], y];
ypl = Collect[xpoly, y, Simplify]
Collect[Coefficient[xpoly, y^2] y^2 +
   Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[xpoly, y], y] y +
   Select[xpoly, FreeQ[y]], y, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &] == 0
discx = Factor[Discriminant[xpoly, y]]   (*discriminant*)
frist = Solve[eqs, {x, y}] // FullSimplify;
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = {x, y} /. frist;
second = {x1 + x2, x1 x2, y1 + y2, y1 y2} // FullSimplify
thrid = {x1 x2 + y1 y2, x1 y2 + x2 y1} // FullSimplify
slope = -CoefficientList[polyex[[2]], y][[2]];    (*k*)
intercept = -CoefficientList[CoefficientList[polyex[[2]], y][[1]],
     x][[1]] ;  (*m*)
Chordlength =
 FullSimplify[
  Sqrt[1 + slope^2] Sqrt[(y1 + y2)^2 - 4 y1 y2]]    (*AbsAB*)
Legended[
 Show[ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[eqs], {x, -ax - 0.5, ax + 0.75}, {y, -bx - 0.5,
    bx + 0.75},
   PlotLegends ->
    Placed[LineLegend[eqs, LegendLayout -> "Column"], Below],
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, Axes -> True,
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}],
  ListPlot[{{Tooltip[Callout[pts[[1]], "A", Before]]}, {Tooltip[
      Callout[pts[[2]], "B", Above]]}},
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]}, {Purple,
      AbsolutePointSize[4]}}]],
 Placed[PointLegend[{Red, Purple},
   Row /@ Thread[{{"A = ", "B = "}, pts}]], Below]]
```

Update 3:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqs = {x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1, y == 2 x + 1};
line = eqs[[2]]
ell = eqs[[1]]
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}];
normalized = First[ell] - Last[ell];
ax = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]]
bx = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]
p = Plot[y /. Solve[line, y], {x, -ax - 0.5, ax + 0.5}];
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}]
(*Graphics[{{First@p},{Red,Circle[{0,0},{ax,bx}],Point[{0,0}]},{Blue,\
PointSize[.03],Point[pts]}},Axes->True,AxesLabel->{x,y},AxesStyle->\
Arrowheads[{0.0,0.04}],AspectRatio->1]*)
(*ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eqs},{x,-ax-1,ax+1},{y,-bx-0.5,bx+0.5},Epilog->\
{Red,PointSize[0.02],Point[pts]},PlotLegends->Placed[eqs,{0.8,0.15}],\
AspectRatio->Automatic,Frame->False,Axes->True,AxesStyle->Arrowheads[{\
0.0,0.04}],AxesLabel->{x,y}]*)
plx = Apply[Subtract, eqs, {1}];
pls = Numerator[Together[Apply[Subtract, eqs, {1}]]];
xpl = Collect[Resultant[pls[[1]], pls[[2]], y], x];
Collect[Coefficient[xpl, x^2] x^2 + 
   Factor@FactorTerms[Coefficient[xpl, x], x] x + 
   Select[xpl, FreeQ[x]], x, # &, Defer[+##]~Reverse~2 &] == 0
Collect[xpl, x, Simplify];
pl = {% == 0}
discx = Factor[Discriminant[xpl, x]]   (*discriminant*)
frist = Solve[eqs, {x, y}] // FullSimplify;
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = {x, y} /. frist;
second = {x1 + x2, x1 x2, y1 + y2, y1 y2, 
   y1 y2/(x1 x2), (x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2} // FullSimplify
thrid = {x1 x2 + y1 y2, x1 y2 + x2 y1} // FullSimplify
slope = CoefficientList[line[[2]], x][[2]];    (*k*)
intercept = CoefficientList[line[[2]], x][[1]];  (*m*)
Chordlength = 
 FullSimplify[
  Sqrt[1 + slope^2] Sqrt[(x1 + x2)^2 - 4 x1 x2]]    (*AbsAB*)
area = 1/2 Chordlength Sqrt[intercept^2]/Sqrt[slope^2 + 1] // 
  FullSimplify
Legended[
 Show[ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[eqs], {x, -ax - 0.5, ax + 0.75}, {y, -bx - 0.5, 
    bx + 0.75}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[eqs, LegendLayout -> "Column"], Below], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
   ImageSize -> 500], 
  ListPlot[{{Tooltip[Callout[pts[[1]], "A", Before]]}, {Tooltip[
      Callout[pts[[2]], "B", Above]]}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]}, {Purple, 
      AbsolutePointSize[4]}}]], 
 Placed[PointLegend[{Red, Purple}, 
   Row /@ Thread[{{"A = ", "B = "}, pts}]], Below]]
```

Update 4:

This method only displays the coordinates of the intersection point, and the adaptive size

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{eqs}, {x, -ax - 1, ax + 1}, {y, -bx - 0.5, bx + 0.5}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts], Black, 
   Text[Framed[Column[{pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]]}, {.15, 1.1}], 
   Text[Framed[Column[{pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {pts[[2, 1]], 
     pts[[2, 2]]}, {-0.01, -1.4}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[eqs, {0.13, 0.9}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Full]
```

Comment: Look at "Text" in the help. Eventually you are also interested in "Style

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

line = x == 2 y + 1;
ell = x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1;
eqs = {ell, line};
pts = SolveValues[{line, ell}, {x, y}];
normalized = First[ell] - Last[ell];
ax = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]];
bx = Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]];
params = {a -> Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]], 
   b -> Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]]};

Legended[
 Show[
  ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[eqs], {x, -ax - 0.5, ax + 0.75}, {y, -bx - 0.5, 
    bx + 0.75}, PlotLegends -> Placed[
     LineLegend[eqs, LegendLayout -> "Column"],
     Below],
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}],
  ListPlot[{
    {Tooltip[Callout[pts[[1]], "A", Before]]},
    {Tooltip[Callout[pts[[2]], "B", Above]]}},
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]}, {Green, 
      AbsolutePointSize[4]}}]],
 Placed[
  PointLegend[{Red, Green}, Row /@ Thread[{{"A = ", "B = "}, N[pts]}]],
  Below]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can the coordinate value of the intersection point show the exact value? Displays exact values instead of decimal values. With a root sign or something

Comment: ```Placed[PointLegend[{Red, Green}, 
   Row /@ Thread[{{"A = ", "B = "}, pts}]], Below]]```

Comment: How to adjust the size of A and B in the figure?

Comment: Use Style (see docs)

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** addressing the comment

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{eqs},
 {x, -ax - 1, ax + 1},
 {y, -bx - 0.5, bx + 0.5},
 Epilog -> {
   Red,
   PointSize[0.02],
   Point[gpts],
   Black,
   Text[Framed[Column[{gpts[[1, 1]], gpts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {gpts[[1, 1]], gpts[[1, 2]]}, {2.2, -1.1}],
    Text[Framed[Column[{gpts[[1, 1]], gpts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {gpts[[2, 1]], 
     gpts[[2, 2]]}, {-0.5, -2.7}]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[eqs, {0.13, 0.9}],
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Frame -> False,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

> [image: pb]

**Original**

> [image: plot]

**Code**

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{eqs},
 {x, -ax - 1, ax + 1},
 {y, -bx - 0.5, bx + 0.5},
 Epilog -> {
   Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[gpts],
   Black,
   Text[Framed[Column[{gpts[[1, 1]], gpts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {gpts[[1, 1]], gpts[[1, 2]]}, {.15, 1.1}], 
   Text[Framed[Column[{gpts[[1, 1]], gpts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {gpts[[2, 1]], 
     gpts[[2, 2]]}, {-0.01, -1.4}]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[eqs, {0.13, 0.9}],
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Frame -> False,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

Comment: ```ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{eqs}, {x, -ax - 3, ax + 3}, {y, -bx - 3, bx + 3}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts], Black, 
   Text[Framed[Column[{pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]]}, {.15, 1.1}], 
   Text[Framed[Column[{pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {pts[[2, 1]], 
     pts[[2, 2]]}, {-0.01, -1.4}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[eqs, {0.13, 0.9}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> 300]```

Comment: Can pictures adapt to size? That is to say, the image can be automatically resized so that the coordinate value and image of the point can be displayed completely

Comment: @csn899 have a look at the edit, please. is this what you meant?

Comment: ```ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{eqs}, {x, -ax - 1, ax + 1}, {y, -bx - 0.5, bx + 0.5}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts], Black, 
   Text[Framed[Column[{pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]]}, {.15, 1.1}], 
   Text[Framed[Column[{pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]]}], 
     Background -> White], {pts[[2, 1]], 
     pts[[2, 2]]}, {-0.01, -1.4}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[eqs, {0.13, 0.9}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> 450]```

Comment: @csn899 I am sorry, but you are just showing some code and I don't understand what point you're trying to make

Comment: Changing the size of the picture can solve this problem

Comment: @csn899 yes, exactly. this is what I tried to demonstrate :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eq1 = x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1;
eq2 = x == 2 y + 1;
pts = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}];
sf = StringForm["(``,``)", NumberForm[x, {4, 2}], 
     NumberForm[y, {4, 2}]] /. pts // N;
valp = {x, y} /. pts;
ofs = {{1.2, 0}, {-1.2, 0}};
ContourPlot[{eq1, eq2} // Evaluate
 , {x, -5, 5}, {y, -4, 4}
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Frame -> False
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesLabel -> {x, y}
 , Ticks -> {Range[-6, 6], Range[-4, 4]}
 , AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{-0.04, 0.04}
   , {-0.04, 0.04}]
 , ImageSize -> 500
 , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1]
 , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]
   , Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ valp
   , Black, 
   MapThread[
    Text[Style[#1, 12, FontFamily -> "Courier"], #2, #3] &, {sf, valp,
      ofs}]
   , Black, MapThread[Text[#1, #2, {-0.2, -1.5}] &, {{"A", "B"}, valp}]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Can the coordinate value of the intersection point show the exact value? Displays exact values instead of decimal values. With a root sign or something

Comment: ```NumberForm[y, {4, 2}]] /. pts```

Comment: Can pictures adapt to size? That is to say, the image can be automatically resized so that the coordinate value and image of the point can be displayed completely

Comment: Text does not scale as far as I understand it. You can drag and scale the image, but the text size will be constant. You could do additional processing and determine the bounding box, but it will change from function to function.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[f, g, A, B];
g = x - (2 y + 1);
f = x^2/4^2 + y^2/3^2 - 1;
{A, B} = SolveValues[{f == 0, g == 0}, {x, y}, Reals];
Legended[
 ContourPlot[{f == 0, g == 0}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  Epilog -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[A]}, 
    Arrow[{A + {-.5, -1}, A}], 
    Text[Style["A", 14], A + {-.5, -1}, {.5, 1}], 
    Arrow[{A + {-.5, -1}, A}], {Green, AbsolutePointSize[8], 
     Point[B]}, Arrow[{B + {.5, 1}, B}], 
    Text[Style["B", 14], B + {.5, 1}, -{.5, 1}]}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> .6, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.04}]], 
 Placed[PointLegend[{Red, Green}, 
   Row /@ {{"A=" Style[A, 10]}, {"B=" Style[B, 10]}}], Below]]
```

[image]

Comment: ```g = x - (2 y + 1);
f = x^2/4^2 + y^2/3^2 - 1;```I want to input the equation in the form of complete straight line equation and curve equation at the beginning